# Entity Framework, query dbset including context changes without to call save changes

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, unit-of-work

I am wondering how to get this kind of behavior that I will explain with EF6.

Imagine that I have my `DbContext` and I am performing operations on it, querying, removing, and adding records on the related DbSets.

Imagine that I have the Person DbSet that from DB initially has 3 records

And I do this:

```
using (var pc = new PersonContext())
{
   pc.Persons.Add(new Person("Mario","Rossi"));//add 1 record
   var pcount=pc.Persons.Count();//still 3 recors and not 4 as expected
   //Complex opertions...
   pc.SaveChanges();
}
```

I would like to use DbSets with the DbContext updates (removed, added, modifies) records without having to call the `SaveChanges` method everytime.

Imagine that before the final `SaveChanges` I can perform plenty of complex operations.

It's not just about the transaction because I know I can obtain something like this:

```
using (var pc = new PersonContext())
{
    pc.Database.BeginTransaction();
    pc.Persons.Add(new Person("Mario","Rossi"));//add 1 record
    pc.SaveChanges();
    var pcount=pc.Persons.Count();//4 as expected
    //Complex opertions
    pc.Database.CurrentTransaction.Commit();
}
```

Is there any way to obtain this without having to write plenty of code considering tracking changes?

Comment: It may be useful https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592872(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an automatic way from the framework to perform what i want since the DbSet will Always give you data from the database.

There is a particular DbSet property called 'Local' (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.local(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Local) that represents a local view of all Added, Unchanged, and Modified entities in this set.

Finally we should write a little bit of code starting from the DbSet query and applying on the result list the operations tracked into DbSet.Local collection.

Answer (score 0):

1.First create a Generic Repository interface :

```
  public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
        where T : class
    {
     IQueryable<T> GetAll();
     T FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
     T Create(T item);
     int Update(T item);
     int Delete(T item);
    }
```

2.Then a Generic Repository:

```
  public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
        private DbContext _context;
        private DbSet<T> DbSet
        {
            get { return _context.Set<T>(); }
        }

        public Repository(DbContext context)
        {
            this._context = bookContext;
        }
         public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return DbSet.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
        }
        public T FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return DbSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        }

        public T Create(T item)
        {
            if (item == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
          using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
          {
            DbSet.Add(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            scope.Complete();
            return item;
          }
        }

        public int Update(T item)
        {
            if (item == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
          using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
          {
            var entry = _context.Entry(item);
            DbSet.Attach(item);
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            var result= _context.SaveChanges();
            scope.Complete();
            return result;
          }
        }
         public int Delete(T item)
        {
            if (item == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
           using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
           {
             DbSet.Remove(item);
            var result= _context.SaveChanges();
            scope.Complete();
            return result;
           }
        }

        private bool disposed = false;
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                  _context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
}
```

3.Create Person Repository :

```
public interface IPersonRepository : IRepository<Person>
{
}

public class PersonRepository : Repository<Person>, IPersonRepository
{
    public PersonRepository(DbContext context) : base(context) { }
}
```

4.Use:
 Example:

```
 PersonContext context= new PersonContext();
 IPersonRepository _personRepository= new PersonRepository(context);
_personRepository.Create(new Person("Mario","Rossi"));
```

OR 
use [IoC container](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx) for Dependency Injection.**(I strongly recommended this)**.
 and Use (Example for ASP.NET MVC)

```
public class PersonController:Controller
{
    IPersonRepository _personRepository;
    public PersonController(IPersonRepository personRepository){
        _personRepository=personRepository;
    }
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
      var person= _personRepository.Create(new Person("Mario","Rossi"));
        return View();
    }
}
```

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Repository and Unit of Work Patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Comment: And how repository will help OP with his question?

Comment: I already use the UnitOfWork and Repository Pattern and i would like to use SaveChanges() and/or Commit() at the EndRequest metod of my ASP.NET Application. Between my BegiRequest and EndRequest i could do a plenty of operation that i won't commit on DB. Any other suggestions?